# Dúvida com switch no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch

Estou fazendo um curso de JavaScript, e preciso fazer um exercício com o enunciado "*Escreva uma função que dado um total de anos de estudo retorna o quão experiente o usuário é.*"

Meu código:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
  switch (anos) {
    case 1:
      anos <= 1
      return 'Iniciante'
    case 2:
      anos > 1 && anos <= 3
      return 'Intermediário'
    case 3:
      anos >= 4 && anos <= 6
      return 'Avançado'
    default:
      anos > 7
      return 'Jedi'
  }
}

var anosEstudo = 3;
console.log(experiencia(anosEstudo));
```

Porém, ele printa no console 'Avançado'. Deveria ser 'Intermediário'.
Onde está o erro com esse código?

Comment: Onde você está inicializando a variável anos?

Comment: @YODA A variável `anos` é o parâmetro da função.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resumindo um pouco a resposta do **Sam**, o mais indicado aí seria o uso de um bloco `if-else` no lugar do `switch`, pois aí vc já faz o retorno conforme o valor de uma condição já testada.

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
  if(anos == 0 || anos == 1){
    return 'Iniciante';
  } else if(anos > 1 && anos <= 3){
    return 'Intermediário';
  } else if(anos >= 4 && anos <= 6){
    return 'Avançado';
  } else if(anos > 7) {
    return 'Jedi';
  } else {
    return 'Impossível';  // caso digite nº negativos
  }
}

var anosEstudo = -10;
console.log(experiencia(anosEstudo));
```

Comment: LeAndrade, obrigado!
É exatamente isso que eu precisava. Falei com um amigo que conhece bem de javascript e ele me disse que o switch não precisaria ser usado nesse caso. Indicou fazer exatamente como vc falou.

Comment: Opa Hardel, mas é isso mesmo cara, programação é assim mesmo, principalmente quando se está começando em uma linguagem. É tentando, errando e aprendendo. Javascript é top man, bons estudos.

Answer (score 6):

Note que no seu caso, se `anos` tiver exatamente o valor 7, não cairia em nenhum dos `case`s e nem no `default`. Acho que a condição do `default` deveria ser `>= 7` ao invés de `> 7`.

O bloco `switch` serve para relacionar cada `case` com exatamente um único valor. Não dá para você mapear um `case` para uma faixa de valores dessa forma. Não existe isso de colocar uma expressão após o `case` ou o `default` tal como você estava tentando fazer. Não é assim que o `switch` funciona.

Aqui está um exemplo válido do `switch`. Note que cada `case` mapeia exatamente um valor:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos < 0) return 'Impossível';
    switch (anos) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return 'Iniciante';
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return 'Intermediário';
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            return 'Avançado';
        default:
            return 'Jedi';
    }
}

for (var i = -2; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write(i + " anos: " + experiencia(i) + ".<br>");
}
```

Mas, há um truque que pode ser feito para forçar o `switch` a funcionar com intervalos ao colocar as expressões nos `cases` e `true` no `switch`:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    switch (true) {
        case anos >= 0 && anos <= 1:
            return 'Iniciante';
        case anos > 1 && anos <= 3:
            return 'Intermediário';
        case anos >= 4 && anos <= 6:
            return 'Avançado';
        case anos >= 7:
            return 'Jedi';
        default:
            return 'Impossível';
    }
}

for (var i = -2; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write(i + " anos: " + experiencia(i) + ".<br>");
}
```

Isso funciona porque JavaScript é uma linguagem interpretada com tipagem fraca. Em outras linguagens que também têm o `switch` mas que são compiladas, tais como C, C++, Objective-C, C# e Java, isso daí não funciona.

No entanto, se você for fazer uma coisa dessa, talvez abrir mão do `switch` e utilizar `if`s seria mais fácil:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    if (anos < 0) return 'Impossível';
    if (anos <= 1) return 'Iniciante';
    if (anos <= 3) return 'Intermediário';
    if (anos <= 6) return 'Avançado';
    return 'Jedi';
}

for (var i = -2; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write(i + " anos: " + experiencia(i) + ".<br>");
}
```

Ou então você poderia usar o operador ternário:

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    return anos < 0 ? 'Impossível'
            : anos <= 1 ? 'Iniciante'
            : anos <= 3 ? 'Intermediário'
            : anos <= 6 ? 'Avançado'
            : 'Jedi';
}

for (var i = -2; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.write(i + " anos: " + experiencia(i) + ".<br>");
}
```

Na opinião de muita gente (minha inclusive), os `switch`es são construções de linguagem horrorosas que nem deveriam existir. Em 99% das vezes que um `switch` é utilizado, existe alguma outra coisa que poderia ser utilizada em seu lugar que seria muito melhor ou no mínimo tão boa quanto.

Answer (score 2):

Você enviou para a o `switch` o valor `3` pela variável `anos`. Com isso irá acessar o `case 3`.

Logo o `return 'Avançado'` será a única resposta. O código em `case 2` jamais será acessado porque o valor passado ao `switch` não foi 2. Além do que as "comparações" feitas dentro de cada `case` são ignoradas porque não dizem nada, não estão dentro de um `if`, que seria o método para comparar valores.

E mesmo que você coloque todas as comparações dentro de um `if`, apenas a do `case 3` será acessada, e retornaria *undefined* porque a variável `anos` (`3`) não se encaixaria na condição `>= 4 && anos <= 6`.

Resumindo, ao enviar o valor `3` para o `switch`, apenas o bloco `case 3` será acessado.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <script>

        function experiencia(anos) {


            if (anosEstudo >= 0 && anos <= 1) {

            console.log('Iniciante');

            } else if (anosEstudo <=3) {

                console.log('Intermediário');

            } else if (anosEstudo <= 6) {

                console.log('Avançado');

            } else if (anosEstudo >= 7) {

                console.log('Jedi Master');

            } else {

                console.log('Impossível')

            }

        }


        var anosEstudo = 7;
        experiencia(anosEstudo);

        // De 0-1 ano: Iniciante
        // De 1-3 anos: Intermediário
        // De 3-6 anos: Avançado
        // De 7 acima: Jedi Master
        // Comenta o que acharam do meu código, eu estou comecando
    </script>
```